# How to get rid of home controller and preserve other controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I my website needs to provide links as follows:

```
http://www.domain.com/contact
http://www.domain.com/category/2/category-name
http://www.domain.com/article/234/article-subject
http://www.domain.com/search/my-search-query
```

So I made a route for that:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{action}/{id}/{name}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

As you could see it's without the "Home" controller in the url.

Now I need to provide access to following urls:

```
http://www.domain.com/admin/categories
http://www.domain.com/admin/categories/edit/12
http://www.domain.com/admin/categories/create
```

So here come my question, how to make "Admin" controller accessible?

Comment: Just add the controller in the url: `url :"{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",` (but not sure what you mean by _"get rid of home controller"_? If you mean make `Admin` the default then `defaults: new { controller = "Admin" ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think "Areas" would work here. Areas add another level of abstraction to routing that leaves your original project structure intact while allowing you to add /Accounting/Index or /Marketing/Index or Sales/Index etc. You would treat each "Area" as a separate project.

Comment: We just want to make SEO friendly urls